# How to embed bokeh plot in Website or Medium?

Tags: python, bokeh, github-pages

I completed a bokeh plot which I believe is a bokeh application. I wanted to embed it in my personal git hub page or Medium to make it interactive. I read through the bokeh docs but I still did not understand how things work. In the document it says to use server_document() function and a URL. Where should I get the URL ? 
below is the sample code from Bokeh document.

```
from bokeh.embed import server_document
script = server_document("https://demo.bokeh.org/sliders")
```

This is my bokeh plot github repository: https://github.com/Lastget/Covid19_Job_risks.git

This is the website I want to embed the code to https://github.com/Lastget/Lastget.github.io.git

Sorry I am new to building web pages. I did not know which file to embed my bokeh code to. I built this git page by pre-made template.  I used markdown in _pages folder to make a post. Can I can embed an interactive bokeh plot in markdowns? Or should I embed it in some other HTML in this github page? Thank you so much for answering my question.

Comment: Are you sure you are running a Bokeh server application? A Bokeh server application is a *program* that has to be started and run continuously, forever, as long as you want it to be accessible. Bokeh can also generate standalone HTML content that can be embedded in to Django, Flask, etc. Let's first figure out what you have. Also note that you will not able to embed Bokeh server applications, or even standalone Bokeh HTML output, into Medium blog plots, since Medium won't allow embedding either JavaScript or iframes. The most you can do there is export the Bokeh plot as a PNG and embed the PNG

Comment: @bigreddot Thank you for your answering.  So I tried to embed my Bokeh plot into Flask by generating a standalone HTML. However, when I start running the main.py file my Bokeh plot shows but without select.on_change function. The plot did not update after selection. Can you please help me with it? Thanks!  [Github_project](https://github.com/Lastget/Covid19_Job_risks.git)

Comment: `on_change` is for real Python callbacks which only works in a Bokeh server application, not in standalone output, which is only HTML and JS (there is no Python process anywhere to run your callback). Alot more information is needed about waht you atually want to accomplish, and what you have tried (in detail). TBH I'd suggest you delete this question here, and come to the Project discourse, which is more suited to open-ended help and discussion. https://discourse.bokeh.org/

Comment: For publishing and embedding, you can use [Datapane's](https://datapane.com) framework and publishing API. This is compatible with your own website or Medium and Reddit. Documentation can be found [here](https://docs.datapane.com/guides/embedding-reports-in-social-platforms), and here's an [example](https://medium.com/@leo_26134/embedding-with-datapane-366e60434b5f) (with an Altair plot, but same process). This works for standalone Bokeh plots, but not those that require a running Bokeh Python instance. Disclosure: I'm one of the people who built Datapane.